# Where can i read this log that ActivityManager: Killing 2225:com.android.email/u0a39 (adj 900): remove task

Tags: android-source, android-activitymanager

I'm searching where can I read this log.

```
03-29 02:47:31.249   774   795 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.email/.activity.setup.AccountSetupFinal: +120ms
03-29 02:47:34.014   774  1200 I ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10804000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity} from uid 10023 on display 0
03-29 02:47:35.488   774   785 I ActivityManager: Killing 2225:com.android.email/u0a39 (adj 900): remove task
```

This log shows in ActivityManager but I can't find the source in ActivityManager.java in AOSP full source.

So would you tell me where is the log source file?

Answer (score 0):

This logs are printed by the files under "frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/" . 
For eg , the last line in your logs is printed by ProcessRecord.java

```
Slog.i(TAG, "Killing " + toShortString() + " (adj " + setAdj + "): " + reason);
```

where TAG is defined as :

```
private static final String TAG = TAG_WITH_CLASS_NAME ? "ProcessRecord" : TAG_AM;
```